# If worksheet name then

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to open a Workbook, it always has only one worksheet. Now I need to check the worksheets name and set a printrange. If not that worksheet name, check netxt worksheet name and so on.

This is what i got:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($RG)

If ($WorkSheets = $WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "Test1"}
    $Data = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $Data.PageSetup.PrintArea = "C1:S60"

If ($WorkSheets = $WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "Test2"}
    $Data = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $Data.PageSetup.PrintArea = "C1:S80"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it done:

```
If ($WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "Test1"})
    {$Data = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $Data.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:Q50"}

If ($WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "Test2"})
    {$Data = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $Data.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:R50"}
```

Comment: Why `$WorkSheets = ..`, since you don't see, to use `$WorkSheets` anywhere

Comment: Right... Just changed it. Thanks Theo!